# Distribution of a general linear mapping of a random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with distribution $f_X(x)$ and $Y$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $Y = AX$, where $A$ is an $m\times n$ linear mapping. What is the distribution of $Y$ assuming either $n \neq m$ or $n = m $ but $A$ is noninvertible? (the case of a square, invertible $A$ is easy, so too if $f_X(x)$ happens to be a Gaussian)

Comment: Unless $A$ has full rank, then surely you don't expect to find a density function $f_Y(y)$, right? It simply won't exist. Perhaps you are searching for another way to express the distribution?

Comment: @Shalop practically, I'm more interested in the case where $A$ is non-square.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered this old question, here's a partial answer to make some progress. Suppose $n > 1$ and $m=1$ and $A \neq 0$. Define the random variable $y = Ax$. Consider the injective map $g:R^n\to R^n$ defined as $g(x) = (Ax, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \tilde{A}x$, where $\tilde{A}$ is an identity matrix in $R^n$ with its first row replaced by $A$. Denote the induced random vector $z=g(x)$. Then we can derive the distribution of $z$ using the standard change-of-variables approach such that
$$f_z(z) = \frac{1}{|det(\tilde{A})|}f_x(\tilde{A}^{-1}z) = f_x(z_1 - \sum_{i=2}^nA_iz_i, z_2, \ldots, z_n)$$
and so the distribution of $y$ is the marginal distribution of the first component of $z$ given by
$$f_y(y) = \int f_x(y - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}A_{i+1}v_i, v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1})dv$$

I believe the same logic could be used for every case where $m < n$, as long as $A$ is row-rank, and $\tilde{A} \in R^{n \times n}$ can be constructed to be full rank.